Weighted k-medoid clustering in R assigns cluster centers to other clusters
I am using k-medoids from the package WeightedCluster in R. I ask for 843 clusters but some of the cluster centers get assigned to other clusters (I noticed this because, when I replaced the labels in the data with their medoids, I ended with 473 labels instead of 843.)
I believe that a cluster center, or medoid, should belong to its own cluster, since that distance is zero and any other assignment increases the distance and is sub-optimal.
I read the documentation and cannot find a parameter to control this behavior. Below is the code, converting a matrix of co-occurrence of labels to a distance. If relevant, I can work to produce an MRE.
wc_package = "WeightedCluster"
.libPaths(c("~/Rlibrary", .libPaths()))
if (! wc_package %in% installed.packages()) {
  install.packages("WeightedCluster", lib="~/Rlibrary")
}
library(WeightedCluster)

print("Reading label weights")
label_weights <- scan("label_weights.txt")

print("Reading co-labels matrix")
colabels_matrix_text <- scan("colabels_matrix.txt")
print(paste0("Number of labels: ", length(label_weights)))
print(paste0("Number of distances (= #labels squared): ", length(colabels_matrix_text)))
colabels_matrix <- matrix(colabels_matrix_text, ncol = length(label_weights), byrow = TRUE)
distance <- 1 / (1 + colabels_matrix)

diag(distance) <- 0


# Find allocation with a certain number of clusters.
num_clusters <- 843  # Number is 2 for debugging, and 843 for around 800 clusters.
res <- WeightedCluster::wcKMedoids(distance, num_clusters, weights=label_weights, npass = 1, initialclust=NULL, method="PAMonce", cluster.only = FALSE, debuglevel=0)

asw <- as.numeric(res$stats["ASW"])
  
medoids <- unique(res$clustering)

# Save clustering assignments to disk. Because they are 0-indexed, I can save simply as a vector.
output_fp <- "label_kmedoid_clustering.txt"
write(res$clustering, output_fp)

print(paste0("For ", num_clusters, " clusters, silhouette = ", asw))
print(paste0("Saved to ", output_fp))

print(res$clustering)

How can I ensure that weighted k-medoid clustering assigns the medoids to their own clusters?

The medoids are indeed assigned to their own clusters. The issue was that I was processing the result of the R code in Python, and forgot to account for R being 1-indexed and Python being 0-indexed. Now that I fixed that, it's all good.
